# jsp form not working when using Bootstrap tabs

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, twitter-bootstrap-3

Following structure:

```
<form method="POST" action="servletName?action=defineAction">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right cancelButton">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right saveButton">Save</button>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Tool" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            code...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When clicking on those buttons, the form action is not invoked, the buttons do nothing.

When I leave the Bootstrap tabs out of the form, it works as it should.

It is not an option to leave the tabs out because they contain information that has to go back to the servlet.

Is their a way to have tabs inside a form? Or to define that when I click on a certain button (on said page), the button invokes the form and includes all the information and sends it to the servlet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your controller you should have this: @RequestMapping(value="servletName?action=defineAction", method=RequestMethod.POST). Tab-panel: https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

Comment: What if I don't use the Spring framework?

Comment: I advise you to use the spring Thymeleaf framework, it is much more intuitive and sure that you will have less problems .. If you do not use spring you would have to use the action like: action=servletName.php?action=defineAction @user3004449

Comment: Thanks for the beedback. I will have a look into Spring framework, haven't had the time for it.
I am currently looking into AJAX. It maybe possible to submit my form with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
//This is the save button which will start the AJAX calls to the servlet.
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right saveButton" onclick="submitForms()">Save</button>

<script>
            function submitForms(){
                //This didn't work because it stops after the first submit.
                //document.getElementById("form01").submit();
                //document.getElementById("form02").submit();
                //document.getElementById("form03").submit();
                //document.getElementById("form04").submit();
                //document.getElementById("form05").submit();
                //document.getElementById("form06").submit();
                //document.getElementById("form07").submit();

                var $form01 = $(document.getElementById("form01"));
                var $form02 = $(document.getElementById("form02"));
                var $form03 = $(document.getElementById("form03"));
                var $form04 = $(document.getElementById("form04"));
                var $form05 = $(document.getElementById("form05"));
                var $form06 = $(document.getElementById("form06"));
                var $form07 = $(document.getElementById("form07"));

                $.post($form01.attr("action"), $form01.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post($form02.attr("action"), $form02.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post($form03.attr("action"), $form03.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post($form04.attr("action"), $form04.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post($form05.attr("action"), $form05.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post($form06.attr("action"), $form06.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post($form07.attr("action"), $form07.serialize(), function(response) {});
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        </script>
```